# SQLite group by range with arbitrary starting number and fixed interval

Tags: android, sqlite, group-by

I have an SQLite table containing daily information. It's stored as year and day of year.

I'm wondering how to group by week (which can start on any day) and sum a couple fields, or if to resort to doing it programmatically. The schema (a little outdated) is:

```
_id      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
hYear    INTEGER,
hDay     INTEGER,
hTime    INTEGER,
hMinutes INTEGER,
lunch    INTEGER,
payWeek  INTEGER,
yearWeek INTEGER
```

And some sample data:

```
17|2015|96|27000000|630|30|13|15
18|2015|97|27000000|240|0|13|15
19|2015|98|27000000|510|30|13|15
20|2015|99|27000000|300|30|13|15
21|2015|101|26100000|645|30|13|15
31|2015|103|26100000|645|30|13|16
32|2015|104|27000000|555|30|14|16
33|2015|105|27000000|570|30|14|16
34|2015|106|27000000|420|30|14|16
35|2015|107|26100000|630|30|14|16
36|2015|108|26100000|495|30|14|16
```

I want to start the week on whatever day of the week, and sum up two of the columns for 7 days and pass that to a `CursorAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the date into a format understood by [SQLite's built-in date/time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), append the string `-01-01` to the year, convert that date to a Julian day number with the `julianday` function, and add the day-of-year number (and then fix the off-by-one error).

To find the *next* specific weekday, use a date function with the `weekday N` modifier.
To find the *previous* specific weekday, subtract 7 days.

That value can the be used for GROUP BY.